# TLS access to Docker for Mac daemon

Tags: docker-for-mac

Is it possible to configure access via TLS to Docker for Mac Docker daemon?

I have created certificates by running

```
cd ~/.docker
mkdir certs
docker run --rm -v ~/.docker/certs:/certs paulczar/omgwtfssl
cp certs/ca.pem ssl/
docker run --rm -v ~/.docker/ssl:/server \
-v ~/.docker/certs:/certs \
-e SSL_IP=127.0.0.1,192.168.50.100 \
-e SSL_DNS=docker.local,macmini \
-e SSL_KEY=/server/key.pem \
-e SSL_CERT=/server/cert.pem paulczar/omgwtfssl
```

My `daemon.json`

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": false,
  "hosts": [
    "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376",
    "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  ],
  "tlscacert": "/Users/anton/.docker/ssl/ca.pem",
  "tlscert": "/Users/anton/.docker/ssl/cert.pem",
  "tlskey": "/Users/anton/.docker/ssl/key.pem",
  "tlsverify": true
}
```

Running `docker` fails

```
export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2376
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/Users/anton/.docker/certs
docker info
Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2376. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I see the same problem after following https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/#use-tls-https-to-protect-the-docker-daemon-socket

Comment: any success on this? I came across https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/6165 and it works without TLS, but I would like to have TLS enabled.